# jQuery: Targeting only the "current" div

Tags: jquery

I have a series of repeated divs with content being injected via jQuery. By the way, the number of parent divs is dynamic, and can therefore be random.

Within each div, I have anchors (H3 a) that trigger a modal window. My problem is, each time the target element is clicked, each section being injected into the parent div triggers the modal window.

So, my question is, how do I isolate each parent so only the current one triggers the modal, without having to excessively use .eq()?

Here's a snippet of my script that triggers the modal window:

```
//prepend modal window to positive message container
jQuery('.rateRibbon').each(function () {
    jQuery(this).append('<div class="modelessWindow hideWindow">' + modWin1 + '</div>');
});

//remove class to show modeless window
jQuery('.posMsg a.showWindow').click(function (e) {
    jQuery('.modelessWindow.hideWindow').removeClass('hideWindow');
});

//add class to hide modeless window
jQuery('.modelessWindow a.closeModWin').click(function (e) {
    jQuery('.modelessWindow').addClass('hideWindow');
});

//when .roomTypeLineItem is clicked add class to hide nested modal window
jQuery('.roomTypeLineItem').click(function (e) {
    jQuery('.modelessWindow').addClass('hideWindow');
});
```

And a link to my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96VKQ/1/) with the entire script.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. You fiddle appears to work.

Comment: Yes. But unfortunately, the actual page I'm working on is behind a firewall. That's where I'm getting the multiple modals. However, I'm trying to figure out how to get only the current parent to show the modal...not all parents.

Comment: Well then the fiddle you provided is a bit misleading since it doesn't reproduce the behavior you're experiencing. A working fiddle isn't much good here ;)

Comment: I imagine it would be. :-o Thanks for your help anyway. I have a colleague looking into it now.

Comment: @j08691, maybe looking at the markup in DevTools might help to better see what's going on.

You'll note that, when one link is clicked, each div with the class name "modelessWindow" has the class name "hideWindow" removed/added for each instance--resulting in multiple modal windows. I only want one modal for the related (clicked) parent.

It could be that you're not seeing them because they're all on top of one another.

Comment: Does this fix it? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/96VKQ/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your second jQuery block:

```
jQuery('.posMsg a.showWindow').click(function (e) {
    jQuery(this).closest('.rateRibbon').find('.modelessWindow.hideWindow').removeClass('hideWindow');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/96VKQ/4/)**

This makes the click relative to the element, and will only select the appropriate modal.